# HTML form JSON array output is not formated as expected

Tags: javascript, php, json, forms, express

I have been making a project about cinema tickets booking, and each ticket has a certain type. I was previously making it with PHP, and I was generating a form to choose the ticket type for each seat with a select input like this one:

```
<select name="seats[D3]">
```

I could then loop over the "seats" array in PHP, and for example seats["C3"] was containing the value "Student", and it was working fine.

But now that I try using JavaScript for my server side  instead of PHP, the obtained POST request body is not a dictionnary linking a seat number to its type anymore. Instead I get something like this:

```
{"seats[E1]":"Adult","seats[D2]":"StudentSenior"}
```

You can clearly see that I do not have a dictionnary structure, the bracket notation has no effect and I just have independent variables, while I would like to get something like this:

```
{"seats":["E1":"Adult", "D2":"StudentSenior"]}
```

I know I could just read every entry and check if it starts with "seats[" and then get the value after it, but I just find it strange that PHP can use this form request to build an array and javascript cannot...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Whatever server side technology, browser will submit same value as per the input type. So just inspect the html code generated for select box when it was PHP based and when its javascript based. Look like the drop down is not getting generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your body-parser `urlencoded` helper to [**extended**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended) mode...

```js
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) //  note "true"
```

This sets body-parser to use the [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#parsing-objects) library which is capable of parsing bracketed strings into objects.